# Perl WWW::Mechanize::Firefox checkbox tick

Tags: perl, firefox

My problem is the following:

I use WWW::Mechanize::FireFox module and when I',m trying tick checkbox - i got message

```
No elements found for Checkbox with name interested\[\]
```

In this site i have checkboxes with the same names but different values. Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="professionArea[]"> xxxxxxxx
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="professionArea[]"> yyyyyyyy
```

I think this is a problem with

```
[]
```

in checkbox name.

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: Could you show the perl code as well? Are you trying to escape the square brackets (the error message suggests that) or not?

Comment: I use typical command - tick.
    $mech->tick('professionArea[]', '1');

Comment: I tried to recreate the message with WWW::Mechanize ... no error. Works as expected. What is strange tho, are the backslashes before the square brackets in your error message.

Comment: Crossposted at [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=952034).

Comment: Looks like this was [solved at PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=952041) with some minor code changes.  If there was a bug in the module, hopefully @user1191282 also reported in the [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox bug queue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=WWW-Mechanize-Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code (assuming $mech is your mechanize object)

```
$mech->tick(value =>1 ); #to tick checkbox 1
$mech->tick(value =>2 ); #to tick checkbox 2
```

Similarly for untick

```
$mech->untick(value =>1 ); #to tick checkbox 1
$mech->untick(value =>2 ); #to tick checkbox 2
```